# SQL query to find how many hours a person has worked in each life year

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014-express

I have two tables

```
Person(id, birthdate)
```

and

```
Workday(personid, date, hours)
```

Both `birthdate` and `date` are on the form YYYYMMDD, stored as strings.

I need a query that returns a table that contains the age of a person (0, 1, 2...) and how many hours that person worked in that life year (a year will include the month of the person's birthday).

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(w.date, 0, 7)) - CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(p.birthdate, 0, 7)) AS age, w.hours AS totalhours
FROM Person AS p INNER JOIN Workday AS w ON p.id = w.personid
WHERE (p.person = @id)
```

This returns

[image: Query return table]

What I need is for all rows where 0 < age <= 100, age should be 0, and the total hours from these rows should be summed. Then, for 100 < age <= 200, age is 1, and so on...

Thanks!

Comment: You should tag your question with the database you are using.  And why are you storing strings as dates?

Comment: try to use `CASE` to set age (0, 1  etc.) and then use `GROUP BY` by age to sum all hours

Comment: @Gordon. Done. I need the date to be a string for another query, but if you can provide me with a solution where you need date to be another type, please do! Thanks.

Comment: Could you provide us with sample input data?

Comment: @tvelykyy. Person: `(1, 19890623)`, Workday: `(1, 19900412, 8)`

Comment: @player, that won't help much. It will be much easier if you'd prepare sample sqlfiddle.com and show desired result.

Comment: "I need the date to be a string for another query" Then what you ought to do is store it in this table as a date, then convert it to a string as needed for the other query. With the format you've given it would be `CONVERT(CHAR, [date], 112)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query over your query:

```
  SELECT     ((age - 1)/100) as AgeRange, sum(totalhours)
  FROM         yourquery
  group by ((age -1)/100)
```

Comment: Great stuff! Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try - This will give the persons age in years including birth month

```
SELECT w.personid, Datediff(MM, Convert(date, birthdate, 112), Convert(date, p.date, 112))/12 AS age, Sum(w.hours) AS totalhours
FROM Person AS p INNER JOIN Workday AS w ON p.id = w.personid
WHERE (p.person = @id)
Group By w.personid, Datediff(MM, Convert(date, birthdate, 112), Convert(date, p.date, 112))/12
Order By w.personid, Datediff(MM, Convert(date, birthdate, 112), Convert(date, p.date, 112))/12
```